# Can't create a bootable (live) usb flash for arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, boot, usb, live-usb

I created a bootable usb from which I was going to install Arch. I did this the following way:

```
sudo dd if=/path_to_arch_.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

But when I tried to boot from this usb flash, I failed. There was no error, it just couldn't boot from it. I downloaded iso file from the official arch linux website recently so it should be up to date. Previously I was able to install mint, elementary and ubuntu from usb flash successfully.

**It preventing me booting the following way:**

After selecting "boot from usb" I was shown a black screen for 1 second and brought back to the menu where I must choose a temporary boot device. When I did it again the story repeated.

What might be the cause?

Comment: Sometimes Uefi or similar configurations fails to boot dd'ed flash. Try instead using tools that have support for uefi and bios, like liveusb-creator(it exists on fedora, archlinux aur repo, windows (https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/)).

Comment: @IBr, I need such a tool for linux (the one I can launch on linux).

Comment: @IBr, sudo aptitude install liveusb-creator doesn't work, it can't find it.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more. In what way were you prevented from booting the drive? Was it not an option in your boot menu? Was it there, but selecting it just led to a black screen? Etc.

Comment: Compile from the source then on ubuntu. rpm packages and archlinux aur packages exists already.

Comment: @HalosGhost, after selecting "boot from usb" I was shown a black screen for 1 second and brought back to the menu where I must choose a temporary boot device.

Comment: @Alex, did you make sure to check that the download and the `dd` flash were good (i.e., use the checksums)?

Comment: @IBr, I downloaded https://fedorahosted.org/releases/l/i/liveusb-creator/liveusb-creator-3.11.8.tar.gz. What do I do next? There are make file and setup.py in it, but what should I launch first? There is no "how-to" or any instruction in it.

Comment: Don't use liveusb creator. If you're trying to boot on UEFI all you need to do is format the disk correctly! Use `gdisk` and your `man` pages!

Comment: @mikeserv, which disk? I won't install arch linux alone, I want to install it along with my current ubuntu installation.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Flash_Installation_Media#Using_manual_formatting If you want it manually. 
http://ifireball.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/running-fedoras-liveusb-creator-on-ubuntu/ if you want to go liveusb-creator route.

Comment: Ok. I'm just gonna do an answer. It really is easy. Give me a few minutes...

Comment: Hey - just to be clear - if you already have a uefi system would you prefer just off of your hard disk? I mean you don't need the usb. I like to keep an extra-large efi system partition with rescue images on it. It's certainly easier. Anyway. I'll just go ahead with the usb thing, but, get back to me I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I'm writing this as I do it myself. I just downloaded the latest arch iso and mounted it:

```
du archlinux-2014.04.01-dual.iso
535M    archlinux-2014.04.01-dual.iso

mkdir -p /mnt/iso
mount ./arch*iso $_
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only

ls $_/arch
boot  x86_64  checksum.i686.md5    pkglist.i686.txt
i686  aitab   checksum.x86_64.md5  pkglist.x86_64.txt
```

You don't need most of that up there. Or, it's better to say you probably only need half of it. There are two images here - one each for 32 and 64-bit machines:

```
ls $_/x86_64
root-image.fs.sfs

du $_
230M    /mnt/iso/arch/x86_64
```

I'm willing to bet you've got a 64-bit machine if you're going with Arch and so the `sfs` image file in the above directory makes the bulk of what you'll need. Still, if it is a 32-bit machine just follow along but from here on out substitute the `686` files for the `x86-64` I'll be targeting.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/img
mount /mnt/iso/EFI/archiso/efiboot.img $_
cd $_ ; ls
EFI  loader

cd EFI ; ls
archiso  boot  shellx64_v1.efi  shellx64_v2.efi

ls ./*/*
./archiso/archiso.img  ./archiso/vmlinuz.efi  
./boot/HashTool.efi  ./boot/bootx64.efi  ./boot/loader.efi
```

So the `hybrid .iso` image works by subverting the `iso` image standard and creating something like a fake partition or something. I don't really know too much about that but if you have a UEFI system the kernel and initramfs image you'll need are in the `efiboot.img` file. In fact, once you pull what you need out of here, you need little else than that other file I've already pointed out. So, now I'll get into `gdisk` and we'll prepare our target efi system partition. It's kind of a cake walk.

OK, I guess I don't have a thumb drive handy so I'm just going to do it like this:

```
fallocate --l $((650*1024*1024)) /tmp/bootimage
losetup -f --show -P $_
/dev/loop2
```

You don't want to use `fallocate` or `losetup` I'm just showing you that I am in the interest of full-disclosure. But, otherwise, what I am doing is what you need to do. For instance, because you likely wrote over some very early blocks on that disk, we need to clear them:

```
dd ibs=4M count=1 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/loop2
```

Now we get into `gdisk`. Substitute whatever `/dev/...` device file your usb disk is on for my `/dev/loop2`:

```
gdisk /dev/loop2
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
Creating new GPT entries.Command (? for help): ?
```

When you open `gdisk` you'll see something like the above go ahead and hit the `?` for the menu:

```
b       back up GPT data to a file
c       change a partition's name
d       delete a partition
i       show detailed information on a partition
l       list known partition types
n       add a new partition
o       create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
p       print the partition table
q       quit without saving changes
r       recovery and transformation options (experts only)
s       sort partitions
t       change a partition's type code
v       verify disk
w       write table to disk and exit
x       extra functionality (experts only)
?       print this menu
Command (? for help): o
```

We need a new empty partition table. That's `o`.

You'll need to agree here:

```
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): y
```

Next we need a partition. At the below prompts where you don't see the key entered it's because I just hit `ENTER` to agree to the default:

```
Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1):
First sector (34-1331166, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}:
Last sector (2048-1331166, default = 1331166) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 500M
Current type is 'Linux filesystem'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): ef00
```

If you hit `L` at the last prompt above you'll get a list of all the available partition types but what you need is type `ef00` for efi system partition. And you're almost done.

Have a look at your new partition with `p` then  follow it up with `w` if you like the it looks to write out your pending changes:

```
Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/loop2: 1331200 sectors, 650.0 MiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): E5D5A761-6AFA-48C6-9BA5-CED0DA2F62CA
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1331166
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 309180 sectors (151.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1024000   499.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/loop2.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

I assume you have a bootloader but you might as well put one on your USB disk too, and this is really easy. In fact, I'll show you how to set it up with `rEFInd` which was actually a revival of an older project and written and maintained by the same guy who wrote `gdisk`.

Get the `refind.bin.*.zip` you'll find [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.7.9/) and we'll unpack it to our disk then copy the arch image over and we're done.

Actually, we'll definitely need a filesystem first. Glad I'm actually doing this as I write it - missing that would have been a dealbreaker for sure.

```
mkfs.vfat -n ESP /dev/loop2
mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
Loop device does not match a floppy size, using default hd params
```

Again, ignore the stuff about `loop` and use your own device. `-n` names the partition. I like to use `ESP`.

Ok, so now for rEFInd:

```
mkdir /tmp/refind
unzip ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.7.9.zip -d $_  
...
$_/ref*/install.sh --usedefault /dev/loop2
Not running as root; attempting to elevate privileges via sudo....
Installing rEFInd on Linux....
UnmountEsp = 1
Copied rEFInd binary files
Copying sample configuration file as refind.conf; edit this file to configure
rEFInd.
Installation has completed successfully.
Unmounting install dir

mkdir -p /mnt/bootdisk
mount /dev/loop2 $_

mkdir /mnt/bootdisk/EFI/arch_linux
cp /mnt/img/EFI/archiso/* -t $_
cp -R /mnt/iso/arch/*64* $_
cp -R /mnt/iso/arch/aitab $_
ls -lR $_
/mnt/bootdisk/EFI/arch_linux:
total 23328
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Apr 22 02:09 x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      228 Apr 22 02:09 aitab
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19882780 Apr 22 02:08 archiso.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       99 Apr 22 02:09 checksum.x86_64.md5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     5142 Apr 22 02:09 pkglist.x86_64.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3979248 Apr 22 02:08 vmlinuz.efi

/mnt/bootdisk/EFI/arch_linux/x86_64:
total 234812
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 240447488 Apr 22 02:09 root-image.fs.sfs
```

That just about does it. You will need to setup `rEFInd` a little bit...

```
echo '"ArchISO" "archisolabel=ESP archisobasedir=/EFI/arch_linux \
    copytoram rootwait initrd=EFI\arch_linux\archiso.img"'\
    >$_/refind_linux.conf
```

That should give you a bootable system. Please look through the main `refind.conf` in `../BOOT` - it's very well commented and pretty much documents itself. You'll also want to head over to [rodsbooks.com](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and read the docs there.

One last note though. If you were to put the same stuff on your system's hard disk on the EFI system partition you'd always have access to the bootable arch live disc.

Comment: thanks. note I already have unallocated space, I made it by gparted earlier.

Comment: @Alex - well, no guarantees then. I really don't like `gparted` personally. `gdisk` is easy - and it works all of the time, opposed to `gparted...`

Comment: The OP just wants to create an install disk: none of this is necessary...

Comment: @jasonwryan That is an install disk. And, more to the point, a separate disk is not at all necessary anyway. Though I do in fact pointedly copy only what's necessary - not including `rEFInd`, that is.

Comment: @mikeserv The archiso just has to be `dd`'ed; tell me why any of this is either necessary or desirable.

Comment: @jasonwryan - first, you get your whole disk. You don't have some ridiculous cd image taking up an 8gb usb disk. Also - you don't need a separate disk at all. You can install Arch Linux from Ubuntu. And it doesn't have to be `dd`d - that's ridiculous as well. You can `cat` the image over a device just as easily, but even that is unnecessary. What you get above is just a regular, workable, bootable efi system partition containing an Arch Linux sqsh root image. You also can put any other bootable system on it. It's easy. `dd`ing a 512mb image over a usb disk is what's nonsensical.

Comment: @jasonwryan - in fact - you don't even need a disk. You could flash your network card's oprom and netboot arch if you want. The arch linux install image is packaged the way it is because it's easy to package that way for the maintainers. You can refuse to learn anything about it, or, alternatively, you could check out the `git` page and do the opposite.

Comment: @mikeserv I guess our respective definitions of "ridiculous" and "nonsenical" are quite different... Thanks for the condescending remark about how I can "refuse to learn": it makes it easier for me to avoid interacting with you in future.

Comment: @jasonwryan - yeah, I can thank you for the same. I come here to learn the mechanics of computer systems - to learn how things work, not boilerplate "just trash your partition table" answers - I can get that at the Arch Wiki. I have no use for proponents of such. I cannot understand how someone can look at a step-by-step tutorial that clearly demonstrates how to handle a boot disk and yet flatly refuse to acknowledge that it has any relevance to question about how to handle a boot disk. And if it was so uninteresting to you, why bother commenting at all?

Comment: @Mikeserv I didn't say anything about it not being *relevant*; I said it wasn't *necessary*. There is a difference.

Comment: @jasonwryan - this is in fact *only* what's necessary. All of the rest - the 32-bit root, the BIOS compat stuff, grub (or is it gummi?), the iso filesystem itself - these are all *unnecessary*.

Comment: why not use usb-live-creator? I was able to install Ubuntu using a similar tool and I installed Ubuntu successfully from usb flash.

Comment: @Alex you can do as you like, of course, but those kinds of tools have two problems: 1. They are seldom updated as often as they should be , 2. They imply unnecessary dependency. All you need are the root image file, the kernel and the initramfs image, really. Too often, i think, people think things *should* be done a certain way because they *have* been done a certain way. What you get from most live discs is a compromise between functionality and compatibility. If you know your target's architecture and firmware type you dont *have* to compromise.

Comment: @Alex - and besides, the above operation is pretty close to exactly what youll need to do to install Arch Linux to a disk anyway, so its not as if you dont need to know how. During the installation process you wont simply be copying a pre-packaged disk image and will instead be installing packages, but you could, i guess. And as i said before, i like to keep those images in a folder on my efi system partition so i can boot to a live image at any time. To update your usb disk all you need to do is replace the .sfs file.

Comment: `losetup -f --show -P $_
losetup: invalid option -- 'P'`

Comment: **Substitute whatever /dev/... device file your usb disk is** - I didn't get it, what does it have to do with usb disk?

Comment: @Alex - you dont use `losetup` at all. You already have a device - `/dev/sd?` something. Do `lsblk` - note all the devices there - remove your usb disk - do `lsblk` again - and whatever device is now missing is the one you should be using. `losetup` just provided me a loop mount `/dev` to use instead of a usb.

Comment: **@Alex - you dont use losetup at all.** - but I did it already. I thought it had never to do with usb flash at all.

Comment: @Alex - `losetup` just creates a loop device - it's just an emulated disk. But you have an *actual* disk. As far as Ubuntu is concerned, this shouldn't affect the current system's disk at all - only the *`/dev/sd?`* device on which youve been working - which *should* be your usb. If youre unfamiliar with your system devices do `man gdisk mount lsblk devtmpfs` and read the manuals that come with your system to learn a little more.

Comment: The question is not what it does but what do I do now? Should I repeat the same but replace /dev/loop2 with my usb flash /dev/sd? ?

Comment: @Alex yeah. Definitely. Thats all you need to do. Be sure to use the usb and its cake. It wont touch any disk but what you specify.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what's the difference between `dd if=/dev/zero ...`, `dd if=/dev/null ...` and `rm -r`?

Comment: @Alex `rm -r` is a command that means remove files recursively. `/dev/zero` is a system device file that will return endless zeroes - its a bottomless pit. `/dev/null` is the opposite - its always completely empty. `dd` is the disk dumper *often called "disk destroyer"* - it reads a file and dumps it into another. In most cases it can be replaced with `cat` but its handy when you want only so much of a file - such as with `/dev/zero`.

Comment: @Alex - so I guess it worked then? Remember - your USB is just a regular disk so you can put other partitions on it as you like now and still keep your arch live system. You can also put other installers in their own folders on your efi system partition and boot them as you please by selecting their kernels in rEFInd's boot menu. It will even work for Windows.I fixed the call to `dd` by the way.

Comment: Yes, but it started to boot well only when I enabled UEFI boot at bios. I think a simple dd would also work nice. However, installing it is not so easy because I'll have to remember each step (there'll be no internet browser during the installation) when I'll be installing it and there are lots of them, though. So this time I just made sure it booted well, then rebooted the system and came back to Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, that means youre not running EFI mode - and Ubuntu isnt installed that way either. Things tend to get a little more simple once you go whole-hog. dd-ing the iso *should* work, but whether or not your firmware will recognize an iso filesystem on a usb is kind of luck of the draw - especially if youve got a computer right about 2 or 3 years old. Things are much better today and earlier than that though. In any case - the above steps are very easily scriptable. If Arch is a little intimidating for you, maybe have a look at Manjaro.

Comment: @Alex There are a few different ways to do that. One could be installing it in a vm to a raw partition on your disk then booting to it by adding its kernel and initrd into your current bootloader config. You could also compile `pacman` and its dependencies in Ubuntu and just use them to install an Arch root. Or you could mount the `archiso.sfs` file we just copied to your usb an `chroot` into then do the install. Seriously - the list goes on. All require some savvy though.

Comment: You said **You can install Arch Linux from Ubuntu**. - could you explain how?

Comment: I suppose it's easier to install it the normal way. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex But about the installation steps - theyre included on the archiso disk itself in `/root` - theres a text file there called `instructions` or something. You can just `less <instructions` to peruse it as you please. Though it might `more` not `less` o  the installer disk - i cant remember.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126841/how-to-make-an-unallocated-space-exist ?

Comment: one more thing: the installation screen is not the same as I saw in the many tutorials and it doesn't ask me whether I want to install x32 or x64. Why?

Comment: @Alex Because you only copied the 64-bit image. If you want the 32-bit you have to get the 686 files as i noted in the answer.

Comment: Nope, I need x64, that's fine.

Comment: the last question please: will be able to boot ubuntu after arch's installation and how can I make sure? should I run boot-repair while I'm on arch?

Comment: **http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?id=5487** the file `aitab` doesn't exist anymore, will your approach still work?

Comment: @アレックス - its called something else now. But yeah - it should.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do so is (as described on [the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Flash_Installation_Media#In_GNU.2FLinux))

```
# dd bs=4M if=/path_to_arch_.iso of=/dev/sdX && sync
```

using `GNU dd`.

Comment: I've written some of it. At least mine was not reliable. I deleted my comment anyway. In any case you definitely don't need both image files. And why use a non-compat filesystem like hybrid iso when you don't have to. I'd rather have  a real partition table.

Comment: what's GNU dd? Didn't I use it? What's the difference with mine code?

Comment: You're using GNU dd. The difference is `bs=4M` and `sync` command. http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync

Comment: that didin't work for me either. maybe I should use a CD instead of usb flash?

Comment: You can try, trough the command has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand how to create a live-usb with arch linux. The solution is simple. I just wrote:

```
$ dd if=/adress/of/iso-file of=/adress/of/usb-stick/sda/not/sdaY/don't/write/the/partition/number
```

I worked a lot with gnome disk utility and gparted. It's okay to clear the partition table of the USB-Stick.

One interesting fact is important. If dd ends with just 100-400 files, then something went wrong. Sometimes it took more time but I abborted because I didn't want to wait so long. Then I did once until it's finished. I'm sure it took about 20 minutes that time and suddely dd shows up with about 10000 files correctly transmitted. I booted the stick and everything works fine. I didn't know about the amount of files and I think if you do it the way I did (as you can see I didn't use the bs=part) and wait about 30 minutes, everything should be fine.

An USB 3.0 stick really can help you.

Comment: (1) How is what you did different from what the OP did?  (2) What are you talking about with dd transmitting files?  … … … … … … … … … … … … …  (3) Note that this answer is identical (down to the same typos) to [this one on Super User](http://superuser.com/a/930810/354511) (by the same new user).