# How to construct a GPT-only partition table on Linux?

Tags: linux, disk, gpt, uefi, mbr

All of the tools I've tried until now were only capable to create a dual (GPT & MBR) partition table, where the first 4 of the GPT partitions were mirrored to a compatible MBR partition.

This is not what I want. I want a pure GPT partition table, i.e. where there isn't MBR table on the disk, and thus there isn't also any synchronizing between them.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: This is how all partitioning tools work *already*.  If you want a hybrid you have to use `gptsync` to mirror some of the GPT partitions in the MBR table.

Comment: @psusi - that's not the only way, though it is probably the best *(among many bad, to include apple's bootcamp)* options. `gptsync` is Rod Smith's solution to the problem, and will *mostly* work with his `gdisk` *(usually available as `gptfdisk` in a  typical Linux package manager)* formatting tool.

Comment: No, you completely misunderstood my comment.  You don't get a hybrid table unless you go out of your way to construct one.

Comment: ***To any comers***: this question ***should not*** be closed. Whether or not it reflects a general misunderstanding on behalf of the asker is not the point - it is ***a very good question***, and if the asker was confused in asking, then, well, that's probably why it needed asking in the first place. In any case, the question is on a seldom understood topic, and it is, as I now understand it, a very representative example of same.

Comment: @psusi Well, okay. But looking mikeserv's answer, it seems a GPT table without a protective MBR would be highly non-standard, what do you think will be any tool able to read a such protective MBR-less GPT partition table?

Comment: No; the *protective* MBR is a part of GPT itself.  You can not have GPT without one.

Comment: @mikeserv fixed.

Comment: @peterh - any GPT-aware application *should* have no problem whatsoever understanding a GPT-disk whether or not its Protective MBR has been removed or altered. A hybrid-MBR only works at all because that is the case - the Protective MBR is intended to warn away non-GPT-aware applications, and serves no other purpose at all. The problem with both of these, though, is that non-GPT-aware applications might wind up writing over parts of the disk which appear to be unallocated to them.

Comment: @mikeserv Exactly this is why I had been happier if such apps would see crap, or a large, unused, unknow partition type filling the whole disk. The second reason was that sometimes I had bad experiences with the gpt-mbr syncing feature of some EFI bioses.

Comment: There is no such thing as an EFI BIOS. There *is* such a thing as a *CSM* *(compatibility support module)* which can sometimes contain  a BIOS-emulating boot module within an EFI, but these are usually no better than hacks as well.

Comment: @mikeserv I wanted to write: "EFI firmware"

Comment: If you haven't already, please follow the links *(but maybe start [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176540/52934))* in my answer. EFI is a relatively new concept and is often understood in the ways it relates to BIOS - which, unfortunately, was decades old before EFI replaced it. The thing is, though, EFI cannot be well understood in BIOS terms because EFI takes an entirely new approach to handling the system altogether. BIOS was an i/o system - it was designed to handle a computer's operations from on to off - EFI is a boot platform and is designed to prime/protect a system at boot.

Comment: @mikeserv Thank you - I know that, it was only a mistake.

Comment: No worries, peter. If you can, try to avoid any special *extensions* or whatever your manufacturer might offer in your boot menu. The best EFI *(for a typical desktop system, that is)* is one which is never seen or heard, ***especially*** if you have a GOP-compatible video card. In the latter case, the EFI can be practically bypassed altogether and the OS is almost instantly handed *(just about)* complete control of the computer. You'll want to remove `grub` in that case as well. Here's [one last link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212970/52934) to an answer with a ground-up step-by-step.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### TO ADDRESS YOUR EDIT:

I didn't notice the edit to your question until just now. As written now, the question is altogether different than when I first answered it. The *mirror* you describe is *not* in the spec, actually, as it is instead a rather dangerous and ugly hack known as a *hybrid-MBR* partition format. This question makes a *lot* more sense now - it's not silly at all, in fact.

The primary difference between a GPT disk and a *hybrid MBR* disk is that a GPT's MBR will describe the *entire disk* as a single MBR partition, while a *hybrid MBR* will attempt to hedge for *(extremely ugly)* compatibility's sake and describe only the area covered by the first four partitions. The problem with that situation is the *hybrid-MBR*'s attempts at compatibility ***completely defeat the purpose of GPT's Protective MBR in the first place***.

As noted below, the *Protective MBR* is supposed to ***protect*** a GPT-disk from stupid applications, but if some of the disk appears to be unallocated to those, all bets are off. ***Don't use a hybrid-MBR if it can be at all helped*** - which, if on a Mac, means ***don't use the default `Bootcamp` configuration***.

In general, if looking for advice on EFI/GPT-related matters go **nowhere else *(excepting maybe a slight detour [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146803/52934)* first) but to [rodsbooks.com](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html)**.

---

#### ahem...

This *(used to be)* kind of a silly question - I think you're asking how to partition a GPT disk without a *Protective MBR*. The answer to that question is you cannot - because the GPT is a disk partition table format standard, and that standard [specifies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) a protective MBR positioned at the head of the disk. See?

[image]

What you can do is erase the MBR or overwrite it - it won't prevent *most* GPT-aware applications from accessing the partition data anyway, but the *reason* it is included in the specification is to prevent *non*-GPT-aware applications from screwing with the partition-table. It prevents this by just reporting that the entire disk is a single MBR-type partition already,  and nobody should try writing a filesystem to it because it is already allocated space. Removing the MBR removes that protection.

In any case, here's how:

- This creates a 4G *`./img`* file full of NULs...

  ```sh
  </dev/zero >./img \
  dd ibs=4k obs=4kx1k count=1kx1k
  ```

  ---

  ```
  1048576+0 records in
  1024+0 records out
  4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB) copied, 3.38218 s, 1.3 GB/s
  ```
- This writes a partition table to it - to include the leading *Protective MBR*.

  - Each of `printf`'s arguments is followed by a `\n`ewline and written to `gdisk`'s stdin.
  - `gdisk` interprets the commands as though they were typed  at it interactively and acts accordingly, to create two GPT partition entries in the *GUID Partition Table* it writes to the head of our *`./img`* file.
  - All terminal output is dumped to `>/dev/null` *(because it's a lot and we'll be having a look at the results presently anyway)*.

    ```sh
    printf %s\\n o y n 1 '' +750M ef00 \
                     n 2 '' '' '' ''   \
                 w y | >/dev/null      \
    gdisk ./img
    ```
- This gets `pr`'s four-columned formatted representation of the offset-accompanied `strings` in the first 2K of *`./img`*.

  ```sh
  <./img dd count=4 |
  strings -1 -td    | 
  pr -w100   -t4
  ```

  ---

  ```
  4+0 records in
  4+0 records out
  2048 bytes (2.0 kB) copied, 7.1933e-05 s, 28.5 MB/s
  ```

  ---

  ```
      451 *           1033 K           1094 t           1212 n
      510 U           1037 >           1096 e           1214 u
      512 EFI PART    1039 ;@fY        1098 m           1216 x
      524 \           1044 30          1153 =           1218
      529 P           1047 L           1158 rG          1220 f
      531 (           1050 E           1161 y=i         1222 i
      552 "           1065 w           1165 G}          1224 l
      568 V           1080 E           1170 $U.b        1226 e
      573 G           1082 F           1175 N           1228 s
      575 G           1084 I           1178 C           1230 y
      577 y           1086             1180 b           1232 s
      583 G           1088 S           1185 x           1234 t
      602 Ml          1090 y           1208 L           1236 e
     1024 (s*         1092 s           1210 i           1238 m
  ```

You can see where the MBR ends there, yeah? Byte 512.

- This writes 512 spaces over the first 512 bytes in *`./img`*.

  ```sh
  <>./img >&0 printf %0512s
  ```

And now for the fruits of our labor.

- This is an interactive run of `gdisk` on *`./img`*.

  ```sh
  gdisk ./img
  ```

  ---

  ```
  GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

  Partition table scan:
    MBR: not present
    BSD: not present
    APM: not present
    GPT: present

  Found valid GPT with corrupt MBR; using GPT and will write new
  protective MBR on save.
  ```

  ---

  ```sh
  Command (? for help): p
  ```

  ---

  ```
  Disk ./img: 8388608 sectors, 4.0 GiB
  Logical sector size: 512 bytes
  Disk identifier (GUID): 0528394A-9A2C-423B-9FDE-592CB74B17B3
  Partition table holds up to 128 entries
  First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 8388574
  Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
  Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

  Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
     1            2048         1538047   750.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System
     2         1538048         8388574   3.3 GiB     8300  Linux filesystem
  ```

Comment: I'd only amend the rodsbooks link to be http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html as it's less specific and more updated to me; the answer is just great otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelShigorin - done. And thanks for the recommendation. I guess I jumped to conclusions about the asker's environment when I read the edit about hybrid MBRs - in my experience nobody even thinks about those things unless a Mac is involved.

Answer (score -1):

In your case and always you need to create a partition >2TB. You should use **parted** command.

Before creating the partition command, we should set the disk label to GPT.
GPT stands for GUID partition table format (GPT).
Use parted’s mklabel command to set disk label to GPT as shown below.

```
# parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.

(parted) print
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label

(parted) mklabel gpt

(parted) print
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sdb: 5909GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags
```

Create >2TB Partition using Parted mkpart.

Use parted’s mkpart command as shown below to create partition that is greater than 2TB. In this example, we are creating a partition that is roughly of 6TB in size.

```
#parted /dev/sdb

(parted) mkpart primary 0GB 5909GB

(parted) print
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sdb: 5909GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  5909GB  5909GB               primary
```

Comment: What are you talking about w/ *you need partition >2TB*? And `parted`, by the way, isn't *really* about partitions - it does some kind of crazy amalgam of partitions/fs writes. I think the whole concept is ridiculous - it attempts to hide the things it does from its user. The biggest problem with the concept is that partition tables and filesystems are nothing like the same thing - and they get written to entirely different sections of the disk. Trying to combine the two things is asking for trouble.

Comment: You have written what again? No, I downvoted this answer because it doesn't make sense, or it makes some unreasonable assumptions about the question, it doesn't bother to address the primary question *in* the question, and the formatting is terrible.

Comment: Setting the disk label to gpt does not make it a gpt disk, though setting a label wouldn't have any effect with an mbr disk, because mbr disks do not support labels. The formatting *is* a little better now, though.

Comment: Creating the partition table --My steps

#parted /dev/sdb
#mklabel gpt
#unit GB
Create the partition
mkpart primary <from GB> <to GB>
#mkpart primary 0.0GB 4000.8GB

The above command will not give you any output.
View the partition table
#print

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      0.00GB  4001GB  4001GB  ext4         primary

You see the partition and the size you just created.

Now type the following and hit enter to save and quit parted:

#quit

Create the filesystem -- You know it with mkfs -t format.