# How to move the bootloader from a hard drive to a usb stick

Tags: debian, grub, boot-loader, luks

I've decided to move my Debian bootloader and `/boot` from the hard drive to a USB stick. 
I'm using LUKS to en/decrypt my hard drive and the bootloader is the only unencrypted partition.

How can I easily do this?  I want to remove it from 
the hard drive, resize any of the partitions (`/`, `/var`, `/tmp`) to get the free space after I deleted `/boot` and put a new bootloader on the USB stick.
The Bootloader in use is GRUB it is on `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: For a better answer you should provide more detail such as your partitioning, whether you're using LVM, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screw `grub`. It's probably some complexity it introduces that leads you to believe this is a difficult problem to solve. If your computer is less than 5 years old or so, then you're probably booting from a UEFI firmware, in which case your Debian-built linux kernel *is already a bootloader.*

1. Partition the disk:

   ```
   printf %c\\n o y n 1 '' '' ef00 w y |
   gdisk /dev/usb-stick/or-whatever-path
   ```

   - That's a scripted shortcut for the options you'd want to feed the program interactively. It will create a GUID partition table and a partition of type **EFI-system** that spans the whole disk.
   - The `gdisk` program is easy to use though - and so you might do better to go at it interactively instead. The target disk should not be mounted when it is run, and you'll probably need root rights to `w`rite the changes. As a general rule you can do pretty much whatever you want in that program without any effect until you `w`rite - so be sure when you do.
2. Format the stick fat32:

   ```
   mkfs.vfat -nLABEL /dev/usb-stick/or-whatever-path
   ```

   - *LABEL* is whatever you want it to be. You should *LABEL* ***all*** disks, in my opinion.
3. Install a boot-menu-manager if wanted. I like [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/):

   ```
   dpkg -i refind_0.8.7-1_amd64.deb
   ```

   - That probably won't install to the USB automatically, so afterward you may want to do...

     ```
     /path/to/refinds/install/dir/install.sh  --usedefault /dev/usbstick
     ```
   - If you use rEFInd, you'll want to do something like this after:

     ```
     mount /dev/usbstick /mnt
     mkdir -p /mnt/EFI/debian /esp
     cp -ar /boot/* /mnt/EFI/debian
     cat <<\TWONEWLINES >>/etc/fstab
         LABEL=LABEL      /esp  vfat  defaults      0 2
         /esp/EFI/debian  /boot none  bind,defaults 0 0
     TWONEWLINES
     cat <<\ONESIMPLECONFIG >/mnt/EFI/debian/refind_linux.conf
         "Debian Menu Entry" root=LABEL=rootlabel other_kernel_params
     ONESIMPLECONFIG
     ```
   - But you might skip rEFInd and just use the firmware's boot menu:

     ```
      efibootmgr -c -d /dev/rootdevice       \
                 -p 1 -L "Debian"            \
                 -l '\EFI\debian\kernelfile' \
                 -u root=/dev/sda3 kparams   \
                 initrd=EFI/debian/initramfs_image_file
     ```

And that's pretty much it. Pretty much forever - no more fuss. The firmware loads the kernel from the EFI-system partition you format on your USB stick. The kernel loads its initial root in the initramfs file. If you're already successfully booting LUKS then you must have already arranged for it to access its key somehow - your key is probably already in the initramfs image. If not, well, you'll want to put it in there - or on the USB.

The boot partition is a *mount* on a UEFI-system - there is absolutely no need for all of the old-timey nastiness surrounding embedding boot-loaders and MBRs and the rest. You just mount the boot from firmware, load a kernel executable, and go on your merry way.

The `fstab` stuff just `--bind` mounts a directory on your USB-stick over `/boot` - so all kernel updates will happen just as always. If you like yourself, you'll uninstall `grub` entirely, though. Its arcane update process - a bunch of scripts that read and/or generate other scripts in a wicked chain - is more than a little ridiculous and the kind of nightmare you can easily do without.

If you'll take my advice you'll use rEFInd, though. It has pretty menus, and you never have to worry about it - the effects of the `install.sh` script above can easily be reproduced *(and is above, in large part)* with a single `cp` command. It's just a static directory called `/EFI/BOOT` on the EFI-system partition containing a little EFI-executable file that tells the firmware where to find the kernel. The *kernel* is the actual bootloader - as it should be.

With the setup above you can boot as many EFI-executables as you'd like - just put their `/boot` *(or whatever their boot partition is)* contents on the USB-stick in `/EFI` somewhere and rEFInd will probably find them automatically and present them as an option to you from the firmware menu - to include Microsoft systems. Forevermore.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you could

- partition and format and mount the USB stick
- copy all files from your old `/boot` to the USB stick
- change your `/etc/fstab` to make the USB stick filesystem the new `/boot`
- `umount /boot`, `mount /boot` to make it official
- install a bootloader on the stick (`grub-install /dev/sdx` or whatever)
- reboot and see if it works

As for reclaiming the space of the old `/boot` to your already encrypted system. Depending on the size of your old boot partition, it might not be worth the effort, as it would probably involve moving all the other data (or an additional LUKS container plus all the complexity that comes with using several of those). You could use it as a crypto-swap partition instead, if you don't already have one of those.

Comment: simpler to just leave the bootloader on the hard drive and just don't use it